# BinarySerialization: Как десериализовать в линукс объект сериализованный в виндовс?

Tags: c#, linux, windows, сериализация, binary

Буквально:

Посредством BinaryFormatter под виндовс сериализуем класс.
Отсылаем на линункс.
Десериализуем.

Первое что показывает лог - "не могу найти сборку\файл содержайщие формат серализуемого объекта"

Документация Майкрософт подтверждает что требуется одинаковый ресурс.
Выделяю ресурс в отдельную длл библиотеку в виндовс проекте, подключаю, компилируется нормально.

Как этот ресурс подключить при компиляции в линукс ?

Comment: чем линукс объект отлчается от виндовс объекта? У вас проблема с кодом? С библиотеками? Вы ничего не показали в вопросе.

Comment: Наверное проще всего не использовать бинарную сериализацию. Используйте любую другую: xml, json и пр.